# Custom taxonomy admin description

Tags: admin, taxonomy, customization, forms

Is it possible to add a short description to a custom taxonomy's admin area?  For example, I've added a taxonomy that determines what kind of banners are displayed on a post's page.  In the meta box for this taxonomy on the Edit/Add Post page I'd like to add a little blurb explaining how it works.

Comment: Is the taxonomy set as hierarchical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any hooks to add or filter the metabox so you can either create your own metabox to replace the custom taxonomy metabox or in this case just use JQuery `.append()`

for example is your taxonomy is named banners and its none - hierarchical (like tags) then:

```
$('.tagsdiv-banners').append('<p>your short description here</p>');
```

and if its hierarchical (like categories)

```
 $('.bannersdiv').append('<p>your short description here</p>');
```

the only difference is the name of the selector , for   none hierarchical taxonomies you use tagsdiv-{$tax_name} and for hierarchical taxonomies you use {$tax_name}div.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the same conclusion I came to and I suspect that's just the way it is for now. :P